# CNN - Choose between two classes shown in 1 image

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently running a pretty vanilla CNN, but I have some images that contain "multiple classes", it is sorting images of digits into different classes (not ocr), however i also have a class called "bad_captures" which is for images that don't have digits. However some images have some features that the bad_captures have, but at the same time they contain digits. Currently the model is predicting these images as bad, but I need it to focus on the digits. Any advice on how to this?

Comment: Put some relevant code and mention dataset if possible.

Comment: @Amir unfortunately it is a private dataset, and the code is simply a 5 layer cnn + maxpooling + regularization

Comment: There are many reason that a classifier not going to work as expected such as unbalancing dataset, small size dataset, and etc. Based on your explanation is not clear your problem to which category belongs.

Comment: @Amir my problem is basically, there are images which contains digits, but has some features of another class, I want it to select the digits over the other class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot explicitly tell model which features to weigh more. What you can do however is to train some simple classifier which will tell you if the image is `bad_caputre` or not. Then you can put that on top of your model  and if the image is not bad capture, then process it. That way your CNN model will not have to worry about picking classes, it will focus only on getting the right digit from the image.

Other way would be to figure out which of those features are confusing the model and remove them explicitly in the preprocessing. Also, you can try different things in preprocessing in general to see if that has any effect on the model performance.